# preg_match_all syntax problem

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Having trouble with preg_match syntax

with in a page I need to find anything like

```
$first = '/>http:\/\/www.(.*?)\/(.*?)\</';
$second = '/="http:\/\/www.(.*?)\/(.*?)"/';
```

How could I combine the two?

Something like

```
$regex = '/(?="|>)http:\/\/www.(.*?)/(.*?)(?"|\<)/';
```

Sorry not very good at this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks about right to me:

```
/(?:="|>)http:\/\/www\.(.*?)\/(.*?)["<]/i
```

Notice a few minor corrections: Your non-capturing group syntax was a little off (it should be `(?:pattern)` instead of `(?pattern)`), and you also needed to escape the `.` and `/`.

I'm also not sure the `(.*?)\/(.*?)` is doing exactly what you think it is; I'd probably just replace that with `(.*?)` unless you want to require a `/` character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a funny thought.

Use `/(?:(=")|>)http:\/\/www\.(.*?)\/(.*?)(?(1)"|<)/sg` using a looping find next search. Extracting variables $2 and $3 each time. This uses a conditional.

Or, use `/(?|(?<==")http:\/\/www\.(.*?)\/(.*?)(?=")|(?<=>)http:\/\/www\.(.*?)\/(.*?)(?=<))/sg` in a match all. This uses branch reset. The array will acumulate as pairs ($cnt++ % 2).

Depends on what you mean by combining.

A perl test case:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = '
 <tag asdf="http://www.some.com/directory"/>
 <dadr>http://www.adif.com/dir</dadr>
';

while ( $str =~ /(?:(=")|>)http:\/\/www\.(.*?)\/(.*?)(?(1)"|<)/sg )
{
    print "'$2'  '$3'\n";
}
print "--------------\n";

my @parts = $str =~ /(?|(?<==")http:\/\/www\.(.*?)\/(.*?)(?=")|(?<=>)http:\/\/www\.(.*?)\/(.*?)(?=<))/sg;
my $cnt = 0;

for (@parts)
{
    print "'$_'  ";
    if ($cnt++ % 2) {
        print "\n";
    }
}
__END__
```

Output:

```
'some.com'  'directory'
'adif.com'  'dir'
--------------
'some.com'  'directory'
'adif.com'  'dir'
```